# Flag weight deputy badge bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, flag-weight

I've been on "flag weight 500 (max)" on main for a while (probably the best part of a day, if not longer), but I've not been awarded the Deputy badge.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Same here since last couple of days my flag weight is at max, but I'm not awarded this badge yet.

Comment: Ah, I know what that'll be; will fix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed in teh codez; so that should get released over the next day.

Comment: plz show teh codez

Comment: 0x02030239204052908cf01304999dd9c9ev02340992

Comment: I presume the 'v' was causing the bug?

Comment: @waiwai933 exactly; well debugged

Comment: Yays! (No more oh noes.)

Comment: Just been awarded, so I'm guessing the fix is live now. Hmm... wish it was a real deputy badge. (Runs off to find an adult to help with the scissors and glue, etc.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka careful now!